# How to change icon position of semantic-ui react Accordion?

Tags: reactjs, accordion, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

The semantic-ui React [page](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/accordion/) has an example of an Accordion with the icon on the right hand side.

[image]

But the code doesn't explain how that is done. The Accordion component doesn't have icon props to change the icon or the position of the icon in shorthand.

I would like to change the icon and the icon position of the Semantic-ui React Accordion in shorthand, ie, without having to maintain the component state manually eg: `<Accordion defaultActiveIndex={0} panels={panels} />`

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar issue where I wanted to get rid of the icon via shorthand, it took looking at the source code to figure it out. If the `content` property is set for the Accordion.Title (or in your case the title prop in the shorthand) by default the dropdown icon is added, if not an icon can be added by using the `children` property.

If you want to control the icon(using the [example](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/accordion/#types-standard-shorthand) from the react site as a starting point) :

```
const panels = [
  {
    key: 'what-is-dog',
    title: {
      children:(
       /*add your icon and/or styles here*/
        <span>
          <Icon name='random'/>
        </span>
      )
    },
   . . .
  },
]
```

Note that `title: 'some value'` is the same as setting the content.

Comment: Been racking my brain trying to solve this. Very helpful; thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Simply switch the `<Icon />` component's position to be after the text.  I.E.

```
 <Accordion>
    <Accordion.Title active={activeIndex === 0} index={0} onClick={this.handleClick}>
      <Icon name='dropdown' />
      What is a dog?
    </Accordion.Title>
    <Accordion.Content active={activeIndex === 0}>
      <p>
        A dog is a type of domesticated animal. Known for its loyalty and 
        faithfulness, it can
        be found as a welcome guest in many households across the world.
      </p>
    </Accordion.Content>
```

Is on the left, but the following displays the Icon on the right:

```
 <Accordion>
    <Accordion.Title active={activeIndex === 0} index={0} onClick={this.handleClick}>
        What is a dog?
       <Icon name='dropdown' />
    </Accordion.Title>
    <Accordion.Content active={activeIndex === 0}>
      <p>
        A dog is a type of domesticated animal. Known for its loyalty and 
         faithfulness, it can
        be found as a welcome guest in many households across the world.
      </p>
    </Accordion.Content>
```

Additionally, you can pass styles to the prop as well, if you want to space the Icon, such as:

```
<Icon name='dropdown' style={{"marginLeft": '2em' }} />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'd like to do it in shorthand

Comment: Hi @ben, I did some further research, I found you could pass ```styled``` and ```vertical``` to the shorthand component.  You can also nest your content if you desire, like ```content:( <Fragment><Label color='blue' content={faker.lorem.sentence()} /> <Icon /> </Fragment);```, but that only adds an icon.  Finally, you can change the root component by passing ```<Accordion as={Menu} />```, but it doesn't quite solve your problem, I'm afraid

Comment: Thanks @LukeT for all the suggestions! You've been very resourceful. I'm afraid I've already tried the 2nd and 3rd suggestion but as List. The second was the best, but still couldn't find how to remove the carat added by default :(

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more help. I agree with you though, it's very strange they have an example posted in their docs with no mention of Icon positioning at all.